# django-Cachops hitting so many get request to redis

Tags: redis, django-cache

I have implemented caching in my project using django-cacheops==7.0.1

CACHEOPS_REDIS = env("REDIS_URL")

CACHEOPS_DEFAULTS = {"timeout": 60 * 60}

```
CACHEOPS = {
    "app1.*": {"ops": "get"},
    "app2.*": {"ops": "get"},
}
```

this is creating so many get calls ,like image shows 2432 get calls made to redis increasing overall time of API. is this the default behaviour of redis or am I missing something?
[image]